# Disable OS-level caching

Tags: linux, files, process, memory

I want to be able to prevent the OS from caching in memory either:

1. A particular file, **or**
2. Any file a particular process accesses (i.e. by specifying a pid)

Either would be helpful since I don't have access to the library code that is opening the file(s). The files accessed are read-only.

Comment: Why...? If you just want to benchmark the process without the cache interfering, you can tell the kernel to drop the cache: http://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches

Comment: I don't believe that it is possible to /prevent/ caching - as far as I know, the kernel has to load files from the hard disk into the page cache in order to work with them. It may be possible to remove the file from the page cache afterwards, but I have no idea how.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich clearing the cache isn't enough since the process will cache the file(s) again while running. I don't think it's necessary for files to be cached to be used anyways (`fadvise`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `nocache`. It's a small program that you use like `nocache cmd`.

Comment: I've tried using it; not sure why but it doesn't seem to work with the particular executable I tried running

Comment: @user Is the executable dynamically linked? If `nocache` doesn't work, that means the executable is doing something that is in some way unusual. You should tell us what the executable is and how to obtain it. If you can't do that, you'll have a hard time getting useful answers without doing some of the investigation work yourself: what library functions and system call does the program use to open files?

Comment: @Gilles I'm prepending nocache to the execution of `/usr/sbin/mysqld` to start mysqld; I was unable to find how innodb is actually opening the files it uses to store its tables. After running some queries from a client, I verified that pages of the file storing the table is cached in memory (using nocache's cachestats tool).

Comment: As far as I remember mysqld spawn children for each connection, and nocache can only affects the process it starts itself and that would be the master. I have no idea if you can configure mysql to do what you want.

Comment: I think it's also safe to assume that MySQL has its own caching mechanisms that work independently from the kernel page cache.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich those can be mitigated from its own settings.